# How to write a factorial function?

Tags: java

I want to create a method that finds the product of all integers from 1 to n inclusive. Here is my code, but it doesn't really do what I want:

```
public class MathUtil{

    int result;

    public int product(int n){

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

            result = result * n * i;

        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... In other words, `n!`

- `result` should have been initialized to 1
- `result` should not be a field, but a local variable
- Do not multiply by `i * n`, only by `i`
- To calculate the product from 1 to `n`, it might be a good idea to validate that `n >= 1`

Like this:

```
public int product(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be 1 or greater");
    }

    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Keep in mind that this will quickly overflow for `n > 12`, or if you change the return type to `long`, then for `n > 20`. (Thanks @FredK for pointing this out!)

Comment: Also note that if result is an int you will overflow for any n > 12, and if it is a long you will overflow if n > 20

Answer (score 3):

Well, `result` is initialized as 0. Then, in a loop, you multiply it by something and set the result to `result`. As we know, anything multipled by zero is zero. Consider initializing `result` as `1`

```
int result = 1;
```

Also, your multiplication logic is wrong. Why are you multiplying by `n` and `i`? Just multiply `result` by `i`

Answer (score 1):

Recursion works beautifully here, too...

```
public int product(int someNum) {
    if (someNum == 1) return 1;
    return someNum * product(someNum-1);
}
```

---

In ternary format:

```
public int product(int someNum) {
    return (someNum == 1) ? 1 : someNum * product(someNum -1);
}
```

Comment: Note, I do not check that the number given is greater than 1, which will lead to an error if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
public class MathUtil
{

    public int product(int n)
     { 
        if (n < 3) return n; // no need to do any stuff if n is less then 3, 
                         // since the result will be n... 
        int result = 1; // result must be here
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) // start from 2
        {
             result *= i; // don't need n here 
                          // and you can make it shorter with *=
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Note for `result`; Lets say you called this method with `n = 3`. `result` will be `6`, but it will be set like that if its class variable, so when you call this method with `n = 4` after that for same instance of this class, `146` will be returned and `result` will be set with it. Thats why you need to make it methods variable so its `1` whenever method is called no matter which instance of this class.

Also, if you do make it class variable and set at `1` each time you call this method, it still can produce problems with synchronization if two threads call this method on the same instance of this class, so avoid that (even if you don't plan such thing to happen, its a good practice).